# How to dynamically convert rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to convert rows to columns dynamically, for sample data I have given below query.

```
create table testtable
(
    tableid int primary key identity(1,1),
    tableDatetime datetime,
    names varchar(50),
    tablevalue decimal(18,9)
)
go

insert into testtable
select '2019-06-13 13:56:39.117', 'test1',23.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 13:56:39.117', 'test2',33.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 13:56:39.117', 'test3',10.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 13:56:39.117', 'test4',90.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:01:41.280', 'test1',33.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:01:41.280', 'test2',53.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:01:41.280', 'test3',41.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:01:41.280', 'test4',93.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:06:42.363', 'test1',30.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:06:42.363', 'test2',13.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:06:42.363', 'test3',23.45 union all
select '2019-06-13 14:06:42.363', 'test4',73.45  

go
select * from testtable
```

I want to convert data in attached image format

[image: rows to columns output]

Thanks,

Comment: The last value in your expected results should be 73.45, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may try dynamic sql query as per your table structure.

```
    GO
    declare @query varchar(max)
    set @query = (select stuff( (select distinct ',' +  names from testtable for xml path ('')) ,1,1,'') as d)

    declare @resquery nvarchar(max)
    set @resquery = '
    select * from (
    select tableDatetime , names , tablevalue  from testtable
    ) as d
    pivot ( max(tablevalue) for names in ( ' + @query + ' ) ) as pv'
    exec sp_executesql @resquery

    GO
```

Please use this as per your table structure, this will create dynamic column names for your current table data. Which is further use in pivot to convert your rows into columns.

Mark it as accepted, or comment for further query.